# Reference Error: d3 is not defined. Script is not being referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I recently took my first steps in web developing. I usually could resolve all problems just by looking in stack overflow but with this one, it does not really seem to work.

I am using Firefox 32 and additionally Firebug as a debugger. I have webpage that runs locally with the following HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TestSuite Results_v01</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Frameworks\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets\TestResultsStyle.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS\OLD\xmltojson.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Frameworks\jQuery\jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>.....</div>

    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="#test_case_list" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">List</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#test_case_chart" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart</a></li>
</ul>
    <div>.....</div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="test_case_list">.....
        </div>  

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="test_case_chart">.....
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Frameworks\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Frameworks\D3\d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS\TestResults.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, i have several scripts loaded. xmltojson for the conversion of xml to json, nad has no dependenbcies to the other frameworks which is why i put it on top. then jquery, bootstrap, d3 and my own script.

The script i have parses the xml file (using the first script on in the html), and loads different elements into the page using jquery. The interface is styled by bootstrap and the tab functionality works as well. So far for the set up.

Now, when im trying to load my charts created in D3 in my proper script, Firebug always throws me the error **ReferenceError: d3 is not defined**. I have tried switching the order of the scripts in the html, but then, the bootstrap script woull not work, my script wouldnt work, and so on.. I am not quite sure were the problem is..The order of the scripts seems to be ok according to the dependencies....

When i look at the at HTML iusing Firebug, it doesn't even show me the script tag referencing to D3. It just literally seems to ignore it..

I hope someone can help with this one.

Thank You!!

Comment: Usually, d3.js is loaded as `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` or `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>`.  I'm not sure how your computer is set up at the moment, but I would think that the line that loads d3 (near the end of the code) would not work unless you have file d3.min.js in directory Frameworks\D3\ relative to your current directory.  Maybe you've already thought of that, but it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the end of a tag in your bootstrap JS in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Frameworks\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"</script>
                                                                                        ^
should be:                                                                              |

<script type="text/javascript" src="Frameworks\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```